# How to use protractor to test class existance

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor to test my site. I countered a problem.

I have a ul, the number of li inside is dynamic,

```
<ul>
  <li class='listing-item'>
    <div class='prod-price'>$99</div>
  </li>
  <li class='listing-item price-onsale'>
    <div class='prod-price'>$99</div>
    <div class='prod-saving'>$10</div>
  </li>
  <li class='listing-item'>
    <div class='prod-price'>$50</div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The 'prod-saving' div will only show up when 'price-onsale' class is present. I want to use protractor to test this logic, is there a way to do it? something like:

```
expect(elment(by.className('price-onsale').isPresent()).toBe(true).when('price-onsale).isPresent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax will work almost word-for-word if you rearrange it a bit:

```
element(by.className('price-onsale')).isPresent().then(function(present) {
  if(present) {
    expect(element(by.className('prod-saving')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
  }
});
```

It's a matter of testing the pre-condition first, and then testing the main condition based on the result of the first.